# C How to use struct, union or enum to build a menu?

Tags: c, struct, enums, union

I want to build a menu show number, food, and the food price like the example below:

1. Chocolate cake $5
2. Strawberry cake $4
   ...

And also need to have a look up function, for example:
If I enter 1, then it will tell me it is Chocolate cake and it is $5.
I have thought of put struct into enum but it cant work

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10

struct price{
    char name[20];
    int price;
};
enum menu{
    struct price menu[10];
    struct price menu[0] = 1;
    struct price menu[1] = 2;
    struct price price[2] = 3;
    struct price price[3] = 4;
    struct price price[4] = 5;
    struct price price[5] = 6;
    struct price price[6] = 7;
    struct price price[7] = 8;
    struct price price[8] = 9;
    struct price price[9] = 10;
};
int main(void){
    struct price menu[0] = {"Cheese Cake", 90};
    struct price menu[1] = {"Chocolate Cake", 90};
    struct price price[2] = {"Macha Cake", 90};
    struct price price[3] = {"Strawberry Cake", 90};
    struct price price[4] = {"Pancake", 90};
    struct price price[5] = {"Juice", 90}
    struct price price[6] = {"Red tea", 90};
    struct price price[7] = {"Green tea", 90};
    struct price price[8] = {"Bread", 90}
    struct price price[9] = {"Flower Tea", 90};
    printf("Please enter the number: ");
    //scanf("%d", )
}
```

I think the way I use enum and struct is wrong. And I found out that I can not enter the number to search for the right food and its price if I write code in this way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an array rather than an enum?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad. Show us **how** you use those data structures in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enumeration` or `enum` is a user defined datatype in `C` language. It is used to assign names to the integral constants which makes a program easy to read and maintain. The keyword “enum” is used to declare an enumeration. so you cant use structs inside enum!

one way to do this is by declaring an array of `price structs` with the size of the enum ( the menu) and then accessing this array by the enum choise, see below:

```
typedef enum menu{
   Cheese_Cake = 0,
   Chocolate_Cake = 1,
   ....
   ....
   
} menu;

struct price menu_arr[MAXSIZE ];
```

Now initialize the menu_arr (structs array), to be aligned to the enum menu. see below:

```
strncpy(menu_arr[0].name,"Cheese Cake",19);
menu_arr[0].price = 90;
. . .
/*kepp initializing all the menu array one by one*/
. . .

void chose_from_menu(menu user_choice)
{
    printf("your choice is: %s, and the price is: %d !", menu_arr[user_choice].name, menu_arr[user_choice].price)
    ...
    ...
    /*you can do what ever you like here*/
}
```

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - my bad sorry! fixed;; see the fix above. this what happens when you jump from c to python and vise versa :-)

Comment: Your use of `strncpy()` is unsafe if the source string is 19 characters or longer, since in that case it will not write a NUL byte to the destination. If you want to use `strncpy()`, always add the NUL byte manually at the end of the destination buffer. In this case, I'd rather use `const char *name` inside `struct price`, and avoid having to copy strings at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the menu list, since you are using a hard coded menu, you could do something like the following definitions to create the menu.

I have modified the `struct` you provided to include a Product Line Number or PLU which is a standard identifier for items in a store. PLUs are assigned to each item in a store and are used on bar codes as well.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long ulPlu;
    char  szMnemonic[30];
    long  lPrice;
} MenuItem;

MenuItem myMenu[] = {
    {11, "Cheese Cake", 90},
    {12, "Chocolate Cake", 90},
    {13, "Macha Cake", 90},
    {21, "Red tea", 90},
    {22, "Green tea", 90},
    {0, "", 0}                 // PLU of 0 indicates the end of the menu list
};
```

Normally an item lookup is done by looking up the PLU in a database. In this case your database is just a small memory resident array of menu items. The key to the data is the unique PLU number which is assigned to each item.

The simplest way to do that is write a function that has as its arguments the PLU number to look up along with the menu list. The function uses a loop to iterate over the array and compare the PLU number the user has entered against the PLU of each of the menu items. Should it find a match, it returns that element. If it doesn't then it returns an error code.

To simplify the logic, I would typically use an extra `MenuItem` element of the array with a special code that is otherwise unused in order to indicate the end of the array. A PLU number should never be zero (0) so I would use that.

An alternative is to pass in the number of array elements instead of depending on a sentinel value such as zero. The easiest way to do that with an array such as the above where it is all defined with a compiler generated number of elements is to use the `sizeof()` operator as in `sizeof(myMenu)/sizeof(myMenu[0])` which will take the total number of bytes in the array and then divide by the size of each element of the array in order to calculate the number of elements in the array.

Should you use the alternative, you should remove the sentinel value or last array entry, `{0, "", 0}` of the array definition as it is no longer needed since you are using the number of elements in the array rather than a sentinel value to know how many loop iterations to do before reaching the end of the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned long ulPlu;     // Product Line Unit number, unique to each item
    char  szMnemonic[30];    // mnemonic for the item
    long  lPrice;            // price for the item with an assummed decimal point.
} MenuItem;

MenuItem myMenu[] = {
    {11, "Cheese Cake", 90},      // menu item - PLU number, mnemonic, price
    {12, "Chocolate Cake", 90},
    {13, "Macha Cake", 90},
    {21, "Red tea", 90},
    {22, "Green tea", 90},
    {0, "", 0}                   // special sentinal value to indicate end of the array.
};

typedef struct {
    int  errCode;           // error code. 0 if no error.
    const MenuItem * item;  // pointer to the item found if errCode is zero.
} MenuItemRet;

// Lookup function that expects array to be terminated with an empty menu
// item that has a PLU number of zero.
MenuItemRet LookupPlu(unsigned long ulPlu, const MenuItem * myMenu)
{
    MenuItemRet ret = { -1, NULL };    // default is the item not found case

    for (size_t i = 0; myMenu[i].ulPlu != 0; i++) {
        if (myMenu[i].ulPlu == ulPlu) {
            MenuItemRet retFound = { 0, myMenu + i };  // found item. return pointer to item found.
            return retFound;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

// Lookup function that requires the actual number of menu items in the array.
MenuItemRet LookupPlu2(unsigned long ulPlu, const MenuItem * myMenu, size_t nMenuCount)
{
    MenuItemRet ret = { -1, NULL };    // default is the item not found case

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nMenuCount; i++) {
        if (myMenu[i].ulPlu == ulPlu) {
            MenuItemRet retFound = { 0, myMenu + i };  // found item. return pointer to item found.
            return retFound;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    MenuItem       transactionData[100] = { {0, "", 0} };  // allocate a max transaction size.
    unsigned short transactionIndex = 0;
    long           transactionTotal = 0;
    unsigned long  ulPlu = 0;

    // as long as the user enters menu items we will add them to the transaction data
    // until we reach the maximum number of items the transaction data area can hold.
    while (transactionIndex < sizeof(transactionData)/sizeof(transactionData[0])) {
        MenuItemRet  menuItem;

        printf ( "Enter PLU for item or 0 to exit\n");

        scanf_s("%lu", &ulPlu);

        if (ulPlu == 0) break;

#if USE_SENTINAL
        // use the lookup function that requires a sentinal value.
        if ((menuItem = LookupPlu(ulPlu, myMenu)).errCode >= 0) {
#else
        // use the lookup function that requires number of menu items to be known.
        // since we know a PLU value of zero is invalid, we do not bother trying to
        // remove the last menu item from the array elements count as it will be ignored anyway.
        if ((menuItem = LookupPlu2(ulPlu, myMenu, sizeof(myMenu)/sizeof(myMenu[0]))).errCode >= 0) {
#endif
            // PLU lookup found this item so print out the item data then
            // add the item to the transaction data.
            printf("%s at %ld\n", menuItem.item->szMnemonic, menuItem.item->lPrice);
            transactionData[transactionIndex++] = *menuItem.item;
        }
        else {
            printf ( "PLU %lu does not exist\n", ulPlu);
        }
    }

    // calculate the transaction total.
    transactionTotal = 0;
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < transactionIndex; i++) {
        transactionTotal += transactionData[i].lPrice;
    }
    printf("Transaction total = %ld", transactionTotal);
    return 0;
}
```